# How to generate a code for a set of numbers that easily determine if a number is in it.

Tags: number-theory

If we have different sets of random numbers, is it possible to generate a code (a kind of encryption) for each set that allows you to test whether a number is in a particular set? (without comparing element by element).

For instance: you have the sets $S_1= \{5,25,46,67\}$ and $S_2=\{14,35,57\}$ and many other sets.  and we want a code $G(S_1)= g_1$, $G(S_1)= g_2$ ... $g_n$ , and ask some how (through modulus, division, bitwise operation) whether the code $g_1$ contains the number 25, 67 but not other numbers.

The solution that I am looking for does not require to be unique but preferable to have a high discrimination percentage.

Thanks.

Comment: [Bloom filters](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bloom_filter) may suit your needs.

Comment: Why don't you simply add powers of $2$, for example, $G(S_1)=2^{5}+2^{25}+2^{46}+2^{67}$?

Comment: This is the kind of problem computer science students learn about in a course in data structures and algorithms. There are several sorts of solutions. To know which are good for your problem you should provide information on how many sets there are (order of magnitude), how big each is, how large the numbers they contain, whether you need to do all pairwise comparisons or just some of them. In other words - much more information about the problem you have that led to this one.